# Metrics for latency or performance of checkpointing

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

We are using Spark 2.3 and we are facing a weird issue. The streaming job works perfectly fine in one environment but in an another environment it does not.

We feel that in low performing environment the checkpointing of the state is not as performant as the other.

Is there any metrics we can look into that Spark Streaming emits which can prove our theory.